# Jquery selectBox plugin - pass multziple values onChange to ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

can someone help me with jquery selectbox plugin? http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

I am sending data from select box onChange through Ajax and everything works fine with one select box. but  I need 3 select boxes. And dont know hot to pass values from another select boxes.

```
    <form id="filter">

  <span>Sort:</span>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
     <select id="sorting" name="sort">
      <option value="asc">Asc</option>
      <option value="desc">Desc</option>
     </select> 
  </div>

  <span>by:</span>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
     <select id="ordering" name="order_by">
      <option value="price">Price</option>
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="date">Date</option>
     </select> 
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="category_id">
</form>
```

`$("#filter select").selectbox({`

```
onChange: function (val, inst) {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {sort: val},
        url: "./filter.php",
        success: function (data) {

                     push data to content

        }
    });
},
```

effect: "fade"
  });

As you can see, I have only one variable "val" and I dont know hot to get values from second and third select box.
I will need it in one ajax call.

**A need sdomething like:** 
data: {sort: val, order: val2, category: category_id},

Also, is it possible to pass some custom variables through input[hidden] fields? That would be also great.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're code is valid, the problem exists within the selectbox plugin which tries to call the jQuery live() method at some point, if you use a version of jQuery later than 1.9 that method is removed, using 1.7.2 which is shipped with the plugin solved it for me, but this also means that the selectbox plugin is outdated.

> Also, is it possible to pass some custom variables through input[hidden] fields? That would be also great.

This question needs to be more specific in terms of how and when you want to do it, but it's absolutely possible.

**Updated to answer the comments below:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        sort: $("#sorting").val(),
        order: $("#ordering").val()
    },
    url: "./filter.php",
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

Comment: Yes, I already change .live function to .on() and everything works fine, but only with one select box. So if I add two more select box I dont know how to pass data to ajax post. I mean - variable "val" is sending select box 1, but dont know how to get variable from second select box. Regards the custom variable - In form I have one hidden input with category_id bat have a same problem - how to send this data to ajax

Comment: Changing the code in the plugin is no recommendation since that leaves you with code that overall will be harder to maintain, my first recommendation is to change the jQuery version to something lower than 1.9 in this case, but it you really want to change the code in the plugin you've done it wrong if it doesn't work and should check http://api.jquery.com/on/ .on isn't equal to .live on any structural basis.

Comment: Ok, I see. But  point is, how to pass more select boxes to ajax function... like this: data: {sort: val, order: val2, category: category_id} - can pass only sort: data at the moment.

Comment: I updated the answer in order to achieve what I believe is what you want because the `onchange` event is connected to each one of the checkboxes, therefor you cannot use more than the passed value in that context.